# MTI/A0: modular arithmetic or elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, keys, key-exchange, modular-arithmetic

In the Handbook of Applied Cryptography (Menezes, A. J.; van Oorschot, P. C. & Vanstone, S. A.) Protocol MTI/A0 key agreement (algorithm 12.53) described as $\mod p$-protocol. The survey [Overview of Key Agreement Protocols](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/289.pdf)
(Ratna Dutta and Rana Barua) describes MTI/A0 as elliptic curve-protocol.

Unfortunately I have no access to [original MTI article](https://search.ieice.org/bin/summary.php?id=e69-e_2_99). How MTI-protocols were described originally?

Comment: I don't know how they were described originally, but this protocol is a derivative of Diffie-Hellman. This can be instantiated with any group, for example $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ or the points on an elliptic curve. If you replace all $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ elements in Algorithm 12.53 by generic group elements, all should still work.

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast Yes, I understand that this works in arbitrary group. My question is only about original MTI approach.

Comment: I also can't access this (easily), sorry. Given that the article is from '86, when ecc was still in kindergarten, I would expect they give it the mod $p$ treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple to convert MTI/A0 into an elliptic curve method. An implementation is [here](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/mti_a0ec).